# Joomla Deployment in AWS, Especially managing common files/folders between web servers (instances) running in multiple availability zones

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, joomla2.5

What will be the Joomla configuration Log, Tmp paths in `configuration.php` when we are deploying application on AWS VPC- EC2 Instance. My VPC is auto scalable, hence I assume that some how the Logs should be in any shared location? or should be on EC2 Instance local location?
Also what will be the path that we will use to mention in our `configuration.php` of joomla.

```
public $log_path = '/home/public_html/logs'; 
public $tmp_path = '/home/public_html/temp';
```

Comment: It is not fair that you give negative marking to the question, without saying a word. The point you have understood from the question may not be the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VPC when we are having multiple availability zones in which our web server is running, there we get common problem on shared media contents. For example in one particular case when `log` or `temp` path, and in case of `images` or `files` that could be uploaded by user/admin or generated by the application.

When Load Balancer directs website traffic to random servers(running in different availability zones) this becomes a big problem to tackle.

In such cases, we must need to have a shared common location that holds these media files (that are uploaded by users or generated by the application). Otherwise each server (in a availability zone) will be saving files separately, and if by chance last time user uploaded photo being in Availability Zone-A server the next time if user directed to (by Load Balancer) Availability Zone-B server the files will not be there. This is a very bad case.

**Solutions:**

1. Preferably it is recommended to user AWS EFS service that is designed by AWS to address this particular need. This creates a common location to hold shared/common files, that can be accessed more like a local filesystem folder. Just like NFS mounted folder.
2. You can use S3 storage which is also recommended in some cases, but you need to modify or setup your code in a way that it can handle S3 storage filesystem.
   Moreover you can also mount S3 storage to your Web server (EC2 Instance) using 3rd party S3FS. But AWS does recommend to 50% recommendation. As AWS may not be able to do some monitoring stuff that helps customers to monitor the traffic and other stuff.
3. You can also create a stand alone EC2 instance which main job will only be to hold these common media files. This can be created anywhere in Public or Private subnet, it will work as far as it is in the same Route Table as other Subnets are. We can use this Instance as NFS by create required number of directories in this instance and exporting them to specific web servers (sitting in our different availability zones) or can also `export` to range of IPs (if we have setup Auto Scalable Group in AWS). Then each client (web server) need to `mount` the exported directories to the locations which and where our application expect those directories. These directories will then act like a normal local directory but will be common across all running web server in different availability zones.
4. If we have a `NAT EC2 Instance` running, we can also use it to act as a NFS server and create directories on it and export them to web servers.

**Conclusion:**
The `space` and `budget cost` are two important factors. The performance is more like similar in all cases mentioned above. When we have media files under <10GB then we either should use right EC2 instance for NFS. But as if we setup separate EC2 instance the option#3 may cost of read/writes in future, in that case option#4 will be more appropriate. S3 is right option as well but when we have option to change the code accordingly. S3 is also right option for huge file sizes.

Comment: My two cents: like a year ago we tried EFS for about 30 Joomla websites and it was extremely slow (big IO latency; and Joomla has many small files instead of few big files; EFS works apparently better with few big file). But I can't be sure if the service has improved the support for the many few files use case.

Comment: More:  [This thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=235976) exposes many viewpoints on the latency issue of EFS.

Comment: @arod, your point is very important. I had setup NFS export on my NAT instance which is being imported in my web server instances. I have not noticed any latency issues as this works more like a local directory on the same system. The EFS may have some latency issues (when number of requests are made to require small media assets), but CDN is the best option to cop with that.

Comment: It was very important question, but wonder why my question weight -2 :)

Comment: unfortunately the wording of the question was a bit confusing, so it might have led someone to vote negatively. In fact, my comment was directed toward the accepted answer rather than toward your question.